# ember.js -webkit-transition effect

Tags: ember.js, delay, transition

I have implemented the ember.js framework on my website.

Now my "index" Handlebar contains a map of Europe and the following handlebars contain detailed maps of the countries (Germany, France, etc). When you click on a country the related handlebar with the detailed country map opens.
Now I want the European map to zoom in and fade out once a country has been clicked. I realized that by css `-webkit-transitions`.

The problem is, that the transitions are not visible because once the country has been clicked the content immediately switches to the detailed map and the transition of the `europe-map` is not visible.

How can I implement an e.g. delay in ember.js for switching between the handlebars?

Thanks guys

```
<html> 
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="index"> 
 <!--Europe-Sec START--> 
    <section id="Europe-Sec">
    <div id="map-europe">
     ...
    <li class="eu16"><a href="#germany_map">Germany</a></li>
    ...
    </script> 

!--Germany-Map START-->
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="germany_map">
  ...
</script> 
</html>
```

main.js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.eu16').click(function(evt){ //Germany 
     $('#map-europe').addClass('zoomIn');       
  });
```

main.css:

```
@-webkit-keyframes zoomIn{
    0%{
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
        transform: scale(1);
        opacity: 1;
        }

    100%{
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: scale(2);
        transform: scale(2);
        }
    }

.zoomIn{
    -webkit-animation-name: zoomIn;
    animation-name: zoomIn;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    }
```

Comment: Can you share enough of your code so that people can suggest solutions that will work with your existing setup?

Comment: That would be too much code to be enough for you to understand. Not able to give some advice with my description?

Comment: I suggest you read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: obviously I have a problem with adding code because it does not meet the conventions of stack overflow. The Help does not bring me any further. Do I have to add four spaces before every code line???

Comment: To add code, edit your question, paste the code in, select it, and use the "sample code" button, or control + K.

Comment: Thanks...Now I added the code to my initial question.